# Retrieving user friendly TSC from a bpf program

Tags: ebpf, libbpf

Is there any way to correlate user accessible timestamps like `RDTSC`  with timestamps from `bpf_ktime_get_ns()` in a bpf  program? The reason of asking is that the kernel time is not related to time that user can get. So I need to find out a graceful way to correlate the kernel monolithic time with timestamps in a user program.

Thank you.